# OpenCV vehicle detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a program to identify vehicles in a video/picture. A main requirement is performace (nearly real time) so I've discarded ImageAI and a model I did using Keras-VGG16 with additional training.

OpenCV provides me with the required performance BUT the accuray far from acceptable: while sometimes it works well, then it fails at the next frame.

I am thinking about possible options:
A) re-train a model with my own images 
b) Use some image pre-processing 
...?

Any help or clue will be very much appreciated.

My code:

```
import cv2
import os
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars3.xml')

#input_path = ...
files = os.listdir(input_path)

for f in files:
    input_file = input_path + '/' + f;
    print(input_file)
    img = cv2.imread(input_file, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 1)
    for (x, y, w, h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
        ncars = ncars + 1
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Example:

[Example of good and bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1o3o.jpg)

Comment: cascade classifier is much worse than deep learning and tylically not even much faster. Try pretrained yolo v3 or tinyYolo v3 with opencv dnn

Comment: Good point. I used yolo models with ImageAI library but it didn't provide me with the performance I needed. I've just checked the example provided by the other answer - in the same line that yours - and this is the good direction.
Thanks!!

Comment: depending on the hardware platform and the deep learning framework you are using, you could try deep learning accelerator addons like the intel movidius usb stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the dnn object detection module?

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API

There are several available model architectures you can play with that trade-off speed and accuracy.

As far as measuring speed try performing multiple inferences and measuring the speed on later inferences, usually the first one is slow since it is loading the model.

Here is some example code that runs on a video:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py

You can set the back-end to get a further speed-up if your hardware supports it.  The best performance I have seen is with the nvidia backend from this year's GSOC:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14827

Comment: Very good suggestion I've done a quick test and it improves very much the detection while keeping the time per frame below 100ms in my laptop with no hardware acceleration.


Thanks so much!!

Comment: Accept it as the correct answer unless it doesn't fully address your question

Comment: It does, but I forgot to do so !